# Why does the sequence of init calls matter in STM32CubeIDE?

Tags: stm32cubeide

Writing a simple UART program using CubeIDE 1.7.0 for a Nucleo-H723ZG board using DMA. A UART DMA receive call is issued waiting for input from a serial port app on the Mac OSX host (CoolTerm). A callback echoes the data received.

When a text message is sent to the board nothing but zeros is echoed back.

I noted that CubeMX had generated the DMΑ initialisation call (MX_DMA_Init()) AFTER the UART initialisation call (MX_USARTx_UART_Init()).

By Reversing the sequence of these two calls the code worked perfectly!

Is this my error, has something been missed in the setup, or is it an MX error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue only affects CubeIDE 1.7.0 users on MacOSX Big Sur. Under Windows there is no problem and the code generator correctly positions the DMA initialisation call before that of the USART.

When using the MX configurator the peripheral initialisation calls are generated in the sequence in which they are entered. When setting up a USART to use DMA to perform the data transfer, two peripherals' initialisations need to be generated: the USART and the DMA device. As the USART was the first of the two peripherals selected the USART init call is generated before the DMA init call.

However, unknown to me at the time, the USART needs to set up a DMA register which must have its clock enabled. The DMA init must therefore be done BEFORE the USART init. Hence my problem.

Knowing this, in the MX Project Manager tab, the Advanced Settings tab provides the option to rearrange the sequence of these init calls and all is well!

So this is a bug. However, using a Nucleo-H743ZI2 with USART DMA there is no problem with out-of-sequence initialisation. Thus far the bug is limited to the Nucleo-H723ZG!

Answer (score 0):

The firmware generated by CubeMX6.3.0 for Nucleo-G474RE does the same initialization inversion (UART before DMA) and leads to unresponsive code.